# Why didn't Plo Koon change his starfighter?

Tags: star-wars

Most of the Jedi of *Star Wars* changed their starfighters from Delta-7 interceptors to Eta-2 Jedi interceptors halfway through the Clone Wars. However, Plo Koon didn't change his. Is there a specific reason why?

Comment: Is there a specific instance you are referring to? The Clone Wars episodes weren't played in chronological order, so that may be a factor.

Comment: I'm talking about his death scene in Revenge of the Sith. He is see using a Delta-7.

Comment: He didn't change it because everyone else changing was a retcon.

Comment: He just really liked it; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Blade_of_Dorin