# Why are there two different ships used by a Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

So I was watching "The Battle Of Coruscant" scene and noticed something. Why were Anakin and Obi-Wan using Eta-2s instead of Delta-7s? I know that Obi-Wan had his Delta-7 captured at Geonosis, but couldn't he just get a new one? Also, Plo Koon was using his Delta-2 in "The Battle of Cato Neimoidia", so were the Delta-7s only used for special occasions?

Comment: Different ships are used for different missions

Comment: But why? Do the Delta-2s have some advantages over the Eta-2s?

Comment: Yes. They sell approximately twice as many plastic toys

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140065/why-didnt-plo-koon-change-his-starfighter (also unanswered).

Comment: Personal preferences and mission requirements change over time. They are Generals after all, they can requisition whatever they need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### In-universe

The Eta-2 was a ship developed later in the Clone Wars as an upgrade over the Delta-7. From *Complete Vehicles*:

> In the last battles of the Clone Wars, some Jedi Knights fly one of the lightest, most agile fighters designed in millennia. Hardly larger than the average airspeeder, **the Eta-2 *Actis*-class interceptor enjoys superior speed and maneuverability compared to the already tiny Delta-7 *Aethersprite*-class.**
>
> <sub>[*Complete Vehicles* (2020)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Complete_Vehicles,_New_Edition), page 85: Jedi Interceptor; emphasis added</sub>

The Eta-2 also had stronger weaponry as well:

> The demands of combat drove advancements in the Jedi starfighter arsenal, resulting in modifications to existing craft and a new generation of fighters. **The Eta-2 was smaller than the earlier Delta-7 but boasted greater firepower.** Anakin Skywalker and Obi-Wan Kenobi flew Eta-2s during the Battle of Coruscant, where Obi-Wan’s fighter was badly damaged by Separatist buzz droids. Some design elements of the Eta-2 were later incorporated into the Empire’s TIE fighters.
>
> <sub>[Star Wars Databank: Eta-2 Jedi Starfighter](https://www.starwars.com/databank/eta-2-jedi-starfighter); emphasis added</sub>

As for why Plo Koon was still flying a Delta-7, that doesn't seem to have been answered in any official sources so far.

#### Out-of-universe

The Jedi Interceptors developed for *Revenge of the Sith* are meant to show that time had passed since *Attack of the Clones* and new tools of war had been developed as the Clone Wars went on:

> ###### June 7—21, 2002
>
> Because Lucas has noted that in these seven Clone War battles the Separatists are still using droid armies, [Ryan] Church sets to work creating new droids and new vessels. The Republic will also have new weapons, and first among these is an updated Jedi Starfighter, the early version of which was seen in *Attack of the Clones*. At the June 11, 2002, meeting, visiting production designer Gavin Bocquet and Lucas discuss how much of the starfighter will have to be built and how much can be created digitally.
>
> <sub>[*The Art of Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith), page 20</sub>

They also have intentional design similarities to TIE Fighters, to visually indicate that the Republic is becoming more militaristic and closer to the Empire.

> "George told me he wanted the starfigher's wings to pop open [below]. He wanted to see a lot more guns on it, too. I dropped them down the middle, which created a great sight line." —Church
>
> [image: Concept art of the Jedi Interceptor, showing TIE Fighter-like wings]
>
> <sub>[*The Art of Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith), page 21</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Episodes II and III are separated by about three years and the outbreak of an intergalactic war. It's completely reasonable to see upgrades to combat vehicles over the course of these events. Wartime usually inspires and demands a change in your arsenal and fleet.

The Eta-2 Actis-class was designed to replace the Delta-7 Aethersprite-class. Simply put, it's just an advancement. It's smaller and more powerful. And that's really all there is to it. It's simply a newer vessel made during wartime.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the size and power (and speed) difference?

Comment: @Valorum - I'm concerned technical details might overcomplicate the answer. At least, from the nature of the question, the exact speed of each vessel doesn't seem as relevant an answer as simply stating the new one was faster.